# building .exe format from matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment

My m file is:

```
   x=0:0.01:2*pi;
   y=sin(x);
   plot(x,y)
```

I want build this program by .exe format.
I want run this .exe in a computer that doesn't have matlab.

Comment: So you want a program that display's a single cycle of a sine wave? Is that all that you ever want it to do? If so, why not just download an image form google images. Do you want to learn how to make executables using matlab directly, or would you be interested in making an equivalent program in another language that would do the same thing without needing matlab? More info needed

Answer (score 6):

Matlab offers a commercial [product](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/) for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Marcelo there is no free solution for your exact problem.

But for your very simple program you could for example use Python with matplotlib to solve the problem and to generate an executable (you will have to include some python dlls as well). It will absolutely suffice and won't be significantly harder to write for your tiny program.

Answer (score 1):

The Matlab compiler is included for free within the base Matlab installation, no additional licenses are necessary.

The **deploytool** command provides a visual user interface for setting up options.

```
doc deploytool  %# Launches help file browser for deploytool.
```

Alternatively, you can write a programmatic compilation script using the **mcc** command.

```
doc mcc % #Launch help file browser for mcc compiler.
```

Comment: It might be 'free' with the base matlab installation, but only in the 'commercial' version. not in the student version. One can't even buy the compiler for a student version.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fully functional option:
If you use a GUI file (such as myExample.fig, to put your visual components), and a .m file to put your code (such as myExample.m), you can compile it with Matlab Compiler, with just one line:

```
mcc -m myExample.m myExample.fig
```

A .exe is generated. You could use this .exe in any Windows computer, without any need of having a Matlab license (you only have to install a MCRInstaller - you could obtain it from your Matlab installation directory: [MATLAB]\R2010a\toolbox\compiler\deploy\win32\ - , that is free to distribute and requires no license).

http://www.mathworks.es/help/toolbox/compiler/mcc.html